# PHPUnit - Am I right in thinking I can't use mocks to test a dependency injection container?

Tags: php, mocking, tdd, phpunit

I'm unit testing a Dependency Injection Container.

At the most basic level, I'm testing that object graph creation is happening correctly. This uses a mixture of reflection and rules loaded into the DIC.

The DIC works using class definitions and because of the dependencyless nature of mocks, am I right in thinking they are not suitable for this task?

Without using mocks, here's how one of my tests looks:

```
public function testObjectGraphCreation() {
    $a = $this->dic->create('A');
    $this->assertInstanceOf('B', $a->b);
    $this->assertInstanceOf('C', $a->b->c);
    $this->assertInstanceOf('D', $a->b->c->d);
    $this->assertInstanceOf('E', $a->b->c->e);
    $this->assertInstanceOf('F', $a->b->c->e->f);
}
```

(obviously this chaining and public dependencies are  only there for the test)

And I've defined several classes in order to make this work:

```
class A {
    public $b;

    public function __construct(B $b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}

class B {
    public $c;

    public function __construct(C $c) {
        $this->c = $c;
    }
}

class C {
    public $d;
    public $e;

    public function __construct(D $d, E $e) {
        $this->d = $d;
        $this->e = $e;
    }
}


class D {

}
class E {
    public $f;
    public function __construct(F $f) {
        $this->f = $f;
    }
}

class F {}
```

Because of the nature of this test, am I right in thinking I cannot use generated mocks for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like an integration test where you're testing the entire DI system at once. Instead, see where you can mock parts of the system--not the objects it creates. Without seeing the classes involved, I can't make an educated guess.

While you probably can't use PHPUnit's mock objects, you *can* roll your own one-off mocks that do the same thing. For example, to test setting a property by calling `Database::setPassword` with a value taken from the container you'd create a mock `Database` class, put the password into the container, and ask the container to create the object.

```
class MockDatabase {
    public $passwordSet = false;
    public function setPassword($password) {
        if ($password != 'password') {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Expected "password"');
        }
        $this->passwordSet = true;
    }
}

...

function testInjectProperty() {
    $container = Container::create(array(
        'password' => 'password',
    ));
    $database = $container->create('MockDatabase');
    self::assertTrue($database->passwordSet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's essentially what I have done with the lettered classes. They are basically mock classes that exist solely for the test. I don't want to use anything real because, as you say, then I'm testing those as well as the DIC. The only part that deviates from your example is that in the real world, the class being mocking may also have dependencies and this is required functionality of the DIC. But I've accounted for this in my simple mocks by using public properties to store the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. This is highly untestable code.

Instead, the proper DI way would be to inject these objects to the objects/methods which need them:

```
A::__construct(B $b) { $this->b = $b; }
```

For example.

Comment: Indeed! Which is what the dependency injection container does--automatically injects dependencies that are required. But because I'm testing this functionality - that the dependencies are being injected all the way down the object graph - I don't think generating mocks will work for the test because I need a true object graph to test with.